# discod js: cant delete music after connection is destroyed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a Discord music bot for my friends by downloading the audio as MP3 and playing it. My problem occurs when I try to disconnect the bot from the voice channel. When I disconnect it, the connection.destroy() function does its job, disconnecting the bot. I have also created my own event, which triggers whenever I type the /leave command, and it deletes all of the files.

```
eventEmitter.on("leave", () => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (player.state.status === "autopaused") {
            player.stop()
            queueOfSongs.length = 0;
            let musics = fs.readdirSync(pahtForMusic)
            let numberOfMusics = musics.length
            if (numberOfMusics === 0) {
                console.log("No music to delete, folder is empty")
            }
            else {
                for (let index = 0; index < numberOfMusics; index++) {
                    fs.unlinkSync(join(pahtForMusic, musics[index]), () => {
                        console.log(`${index + 1} music/s was/er deleted`)
                    })
                }
            }
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
        console.log(queueOfSongs);
    }, 0)
})
```

Every time I disconnect the bot, this event deletes all MP3 files except for the one that was being played right before I use /leave. It is not being deleted, and I get this error message:

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\ivo\Desktop\JS projects\Discord bot projo\music\Bon Jovi - It's My Life (Official Music Video).mp3'

Any idea how i can fix this, does the stop() function even do anything because if i run my code with and without it nothing changes?

I tried eveything i can think of with player.stop() because as i understand it just stops the playback of the current resource and destroys the resource